# Remote call a webcam in Java

Tags: java, web-applications, webcam

So I'm fiddling about with webcam usage in Java. I have tried using this set of libraries found here: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture
All the examples seem to work and I can call webcam opening from other classes as well. However, my current setup I'm using includes a webapp hosted on a Tomcat server in Eclipse EE. When a button is pressed it sends a message to the server and does the according command based on the message.
The problem is that when a message is send to open the camera I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com/github/sarxos/webcam/WebcamPanel
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMessageHandlerBase.handlePojoMethodException(PojoMessageHandlerBase.java:119)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMessageHandlerWholeBase.onMessage(PojoMessageHandlerWholeBase.java:82)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:393)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:494)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:289)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:130)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:60)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:203)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/sarxos/webcam/WebcamPanel
at WebcamPanelExample.handleMessage(WebcamPanelExample.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMessageHandlerWholeBase.onMessage(PojoMessageHandlerWholeBase.java:80)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
... 22 more
```

If I create a main method to open the camera it seems to work fine, but when I want to call it from from the message handler it doesn't. Is there something obvious I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

Doesn't work:

```
@OnMessage
public void handleMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    if(message.equals("Camera"))
    {
        CameraTest.OpenCam1(); // Method that opens camera
    }
}
```

Works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CameraTest.OpenCam();
}
```

Comment: Can I see the complete java files. It seems there is some lib missing.

Comment: Something like import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;

Comment: The code in my class "CameraTest" is just that of the main in this example: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java/WebcamPanelExample.java   Adding these imports: "import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;" doesn't seem to help.

Comment: But are you sure the classes are in the class path at runtime?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have all the needed .jars in the build path, is this not enough?